# How to plot a ROC curve for a knn model

Tags: r, knn, roc

I am using ROCR package and i was wondering how can one plot a ROC curve for knn model in R? Is there any way to plot it all with this package?

I don't know how to use the prediction function of ROCR for knn. Here's my example, i am using isolet dataset from UCI repository where i renamed the class attribute as y:

```
cl<-factor(isolet_training$y)
knn_isolet<-knn(isolet_training, isolet_testing, cl, k=2, prob=TRUE)
```

Now my question is, what are the arguments to pass to the prediction function of ROC. I tried the 2 below alternatives which are not working:

```
library(ROCR)
pred_knn<-prediction(knn_isolet$y, cl)
pred_knn<-prediction(knn_isolet$y, isolet_testing$y)
```

Comment: I guess it can be done since the ROCR package is all about visualizing various aspects of classifiers. It would be great if you could provide a toy example where you show how you fit your kNN classifier.

Comment: @Backlin I just added an example.

Answer (score 6):

There's several steps to solve in order to get you a ROC curve here. I am just going to make up some data since you did not provide an easy way of getting the data you are using. Note that the `ROCR` package wants the class labels to be positive/negative, not factors, so let's make them like that.

```
# Generate fake data
isolet_training <- sweep(matrix(rnorm(400), 40, 10), 1, rep(0:1, each=20))
isolet_testing <- sweep(matrix(rnorm(400), 40, 10), 1, rep(0:1, each=20))
# Generate class labels
cl <- cl_testing <- rep(c(-1, 1), each=20)
```

You can now train your knn and obtain its class probabilities from the `"prob"` attribute.

```
knn_isolet <- class::knn(isolet_training, isolet_testing, cl, k=2, prob=TRUE)
prob <- attr(knn_isolet, "prob")
# you can probably use just `knn` instead of `class::knn`,
# but for some reason it did not work for me.
```

However, they come on a form that `ROCR` does not accept so we need to invert them for the `-1` class and rescale them.

```
prob <- 2*ifelse(knn_isolet == "-1", 1-prob, prob) - 1
```

Now you can feed the "probabilities" into the `ROCR` package's functions and obtain a ROC curve.

```
pred_knn <- prediction(prob, cl_testing)
pred_knn <- performance(pred_knn, "tpr", "fpr")
plot(pred_knn, avg= "threshold", colorize=T, lwd=3, main="Voilà, a ROC curve!")
```

[image]

Comment: If the vector to be provided in the `predictions` argument must contain the positive category probabilities of each case, why `ifelse(knn_isolet == "-1", 1-prob, prob)` alone is not enough to obtain such probabilities?

Answer (score 0):

```r
pred_knn<-prediction(knn_isolet$y, isolet_testing$y
```

This line would work just fine, but according to the documentation, both the arguments must be vectors.

So first do:

```r
knn_isolet$y <- as.vector(knn_isolet$y, mode = "numeric")
isolet_testing$y <- as.vector(isolet_testing$y, mode = "numeric")
```

Note: ROCR only supports binary classification. So check if the levels in `knn_isolet$y` and `isolet_testing$y` have the same labels.