# Plotting Multiple ROC curves, or an average one from multi class labels (multinomial regression)

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, roc, auc

I have a data set with multiple discrete labels, say 4,5,6. On this I run the ExtraTreesClassifier (I will also run Multinomial logit afterword on the same data, this is just a short example) as below. :

```
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc

clf = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=200,random_state=0,criterion='gini',bootstrap=True,oob_score=1,compute_importances=True)
# Also tried entropy for the information gain
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
#y_test is test data and y_predict is trained using ExtraTreesClassifier
y_predicted=clf.predict(x_test)

fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_predicted,pos_label=4) # recall my labels are 4,5 and 6
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
print("Area under the ROC curve : %f" % roc_auc)
```

The question is - **is there something like a average ROC curve** - basically I could add up all the tpr & fpr seperately for EACH label value and then take means (will that make sense by the way?) - and then just call

```
# Would this be statistically correct, and would mean something worth interpreting?
roc_auc_avearge = auc(fpr_average, tpr_average)
print("Area under the ROC curve : %f" % roc_auc)
```

I am assuming, I will get something similar to this afterword - but how do I interpret thresholds in this case ? 
[How to plot a ROC curve for a knn model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741599/how-to-plot-a-roc-curve-for-a-knn-model?rq=1)

**Hence, please also mention if I can/should get individual thresholds in this case and why would one approach be better(statistically) over the other?**

*What I tried so far (besides averaging):*

On changing pos_label = 4 , then 5 & 6 and plotting the roc curves, I see very poor performance, even lesser than the y=x (perfectly random and tpr=fpr case) How should I approach this problem  ?

Comment: Found this paper that describes multiple usecases to solve similar problem https://ccrma.stanford.edu/workshops/mir2009/references/ROCintro.pdf  "Introduction to ROC graphs : Tom Fawcett "

Comment: Another possibility is Grid search to compute thresholds that give the maximum tpr & least fpr. More here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370570/elegant-grid-search-in-python-numpy and http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html#scipy.optimize.brute

Answer (score 3):

ROC curve averaging has been proposed by [Hand & Till in 2001](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1010920819831). They basically compute the ROC curves for all comparison pairs (4 vs. 5, 4 vs. 6 and 5 vs. 6) and average the result.

When you compute the ROC curve with `pos_label=4`, you implicitly say that the other labels are the negatives (5 and 6). Note that this is slightly different from what was proposed by Hand & Till.

A few notes:

- You should make sure that your classifier was trained in a way that makes sense with your ROC analysis. If you say `pos_label=5` in the `roc_curve`, and your classifier was train to recognize 5 as intermediate between 4 and 6, you will for sure get nothing useful here
- If you get AUC < 0.5, it means you are looking at it in the wrong way (and you should reverse your predictions)
- In general ROC analysis is useful for a binary classification. Whether it makes sense for multiclass problems is case-dependant, and it might not be the case for you.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the resource - will look into it. It's comforting to know though that "Averaging" exists. +1 . The other thing I found puzzling was my clf.oob_score_ (out of bag score and prediction score clf.score(x_test,y_test)[Basicaly computes the fraction of correct predictions per "label"] were both in range of 74% , but AUC was around 53% on average - though AUC and these metrics are not correlated, was hoping better AUC - any indications to do this better ?